# Segmentation Fault on CV::COLOR_BRG2GRAY

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

I've got a problem which is driving me crazy.

The following code produces a segmentation fault on CV_BRG2GRAY

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    cap >> image_BGR;

    cv::cvtColor(image_BGR, image_BGR, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    display(window, image_BGR);

    ...

}
```

Some clarifications

- cap is an object which returns a cv::Mat of the webcam
- I've tried removing the cvtColor line and it's working, I see the webcam stream. But I want a gray scale image.
- If I replace CV_BGR2GRAY with, e.g. CV_BGR2Luv, it works.
- I've tried to use cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY and it's not working.

Comment: are you compiling in release mode and linking against debug libraries or vice versa?

Comment: can you try to create another mat? `cap >> image_BGR; cv::Mat gray; cv::cvtColor(image_BGR, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY); display(window, gray);`

Comment: @Micka 
not so sure, I'm compiling a using a makefile which was given. 

btw, the code you suggested is giving the following error: 
`libv4l2: error turning on stream: File too large
VIDIOC_STREAMON: File too large
Could not query frame. Trying to reinitialize.
Segmentation fault`

Comment: can you `std::cout << image_BGR.size() << std::endl` before cv::cvtColor and investigate whether there are unexpected values for images that crash? In addition, can you add cv:namedWindow("hello world"); cv::waitKey(0); before the loop? If linked against the wrong library, highgui often puts some strange windows names in the title :)

Comment: 1. [640 x 480] which is the resolution of my webcam

Comment: 2. Hello World is the title

Comment: It's working if I do like this: 
  `cv::cvtColor(image_BGR, image_BGR, CV_BGR2GRAY);
  cv::cvtColor(image_BGR, image_BGR, CV_GRAY2BGR);`

Comment: very strange... can you try to `.clone()` or `.copyTo` the original image to some 2nd image and convert only that 2nd image without "manipulating" `img_bgr`?

Comment: Try to replace `cap >> image_BGR;` to `image_BGR = imread("somefile");` I suspect it's not the color conversion line that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Micka You were on the right path, but you also need to allocate the output image before calling `cvtColor`.

Comment: @Antonio cvtColor will allocate new memory automatically if dimensions dont fit

Comment: @Micka Gosh, although the documentation doesn't state it clearly, I believe you are right. I wonder then why the code you proposed doesn't work for OP...

Comment: @Micka I replaced `cap >> image_BGR` with `imge_BGR = imread("somefile")` and it didn't work as well. 
But I found out the problem: apparently the function `display` accepts only bgr images, although this was not stated in the documentation :-/
If you want to put your answer ("I suspect that the problem is somewhere else in the code") I'll flag it as correct.

Comment: let @Tae-SungShin write that answer or write it yourself and accept it, maybe it'll help others.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin uh sorry, I misread the username

Comment: Thanks for your offer. But I don't think my comment deserves the treatment as you have searched more to get your solution and I don't know much about it. I think it'd be best for you to post your answer by yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out the problem: apparently the function display accepts only bgr images, although this was not stated in the documentation :-/

Comment: Hey :)
I guess we are from the same class.
Did you finally make it work?

Comment: yep, I did. I had some initial issues, and most of them were caused by my lack of knowledge in C++. You?

Comment: Can you drop me an email, please, so that we can talk directly?
warmspringwinds@gmail.com